# Usar condição if/else dentro de um while

Tags: php, lista, condição

Bom dia!! Estou precisando de uma ajuda. No código abaixo, eu gero um arquivo `.txt` delimitado por `";"`. Porém, dentro do `While`, no array, eu gostaria de incluir uma condição, exemplo:

```
while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array ( $select ) ) { $conteudo = "

if{$_SESSION[nivelAcesso]==3{
$linha[sap];
$linha[descricao];
}
$linha[segmento]; 




    <?php

    header ( 'Content-type: text/plain' );
    header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="EQUIPAMENTOS_DETALHADOS_' . $date . '.txt"' );

    $NOME_ARQUIVO = "EQUIPAMENTOS_DETALHADOS.txt";
    ?>
    <?php

    $select = mysql_query ( "SELECT materiais.sap,materiais.descricao,materiais.segmento,descricaoRegiao,estoque.serial, estoque.sim_card, estoque.cas_id ,DATE_FORMAT(estoque.data_cadastro,'%d/%m/%Y') as dataCadastro,Status_equipamento,estoque.notaFiscal from estoque inner join materiais on estoque.id_material=materiais.id inner join regioes_estoque on estoque.regional=regioes_estoque.regiao where materiais.almoxarifado='$_SESSION[almoxarifado]' and estoque.serial <> ' ' and estoque.serial not in (select serial from movimento)" ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    $saida = fopen ( "EQUIPAMENTOS_DETALHADOS.txt", "a+" );
    echo "COD.SAP;DESCRICAO;SEGMENTO;DESCRICAO_REIGAO;SERIAL;SIM_CARD;CAS_ID;DATA_CADASTRO;STATUS_EQUIPAMENTO;NOTA_FISCAL \n";
    while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array ( $select ) ) {
        $conteudo = "$linha[sap];$linha[descricao];$linha[segmento];$linha[descricaoRegiao];$linha[serial];$linha[sim_card];$linha[cas_id];$linha[dataCadastro];$linha[Status_equipamento];$linha[notaFiscal]; \n";
        $result = fputs ( $saida, $conteudo );
        echo $conteudo;
    }
    ;
    fclose ( $saida );

    unlink ( $NOME_ARQUIVO );
    ?>
```

Comment: Tiago o seu código está bem confuso. Porque tem código PHP dentro da string `$conteudo`?

Comment: Jorge, O primeiro exemplo é o que eu gostaria de ver se é possível fazer. Eu preciso incluir uma condição dentro do `mysql_fetch_array`, para quando atender essa condição, ele incluir mais duas informações no arquivo `.txt` gerado. Deu pra entender?

Comment: Tiago você não pode por `$conteudo = " ` e depois meter código dentro, quando você abre as aspas está a começar um string, tudo que tiver dentro será interpretado como tal. Você pode concatenar string com um ponto `.` assim: `$conteudo = $conteudo. "algo mais a acrescentar";` ou em alternativa o simplificado `$conteudo .=  "algo mais a acrescentar";`. Tente aprender mais um bocado de PHP e de programação para entender esses conceitos iniciais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar o `if` dentro do ciclo `while` e concatenar os dados de acordo com o resultado da operação utilizando o operador de atribuição de concatenação `.=`.

A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/) do PHP ensina como utilizar o [construtor](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php) `if` e ensina também como utilizar os [operadores de string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php).

```
while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array ( $select ) ) {
   // utilizamos o operador "=" para atribuir um valor inicial a variável "conteudo"
   $conteudo = "$linha[sap];$linha[descricao];$linha[segmento];$linha[descricaoRegiao];$linha[serial];$linha[sim_card];$linha[cas_id];$linha[dataCadastro];$linha[Status_equipamento];$linha[notaFiscal];"

   // se o nível de acesso for igual a 3, 
   // então é concatenado uma string à variável "conteudo"
   if($_SESSION[nivelAcesso]==3) {
        $conteudo .= "$linha[sim_card];$linha[cas_id];";
   }

   // contatenamos novamente uma nova string à variável "conteudo"
   $conteudo .= '\n';

   $result = fputs ( $saida, $conteudo );
   echo $conteudo;
}
```

O operador de atribuição de concatenação `.=` é a mesma coisa que:

```
// ou seja, a variável é igual ao próprio valor
// concatenado com uma nova string.
$conteudo = 'Olá';
$conteudo = $conteudo . ' mundo';

echo $conteudo; // Olá mundo
```

O mesmo resultado utilizando o operador de atribuição de concatenação:

```
$conteudo = 'Olá';
$conteudo .= ' mundo';

echo $conteudo; // Olá mundo
```

Comment: Filipe, mas a condição é só para as informações de $linha[sim_card]; $linha[cas_id];. Sendo mais direito, eu preciso que ele inclua essas informações durante o white dentro da variável $conteudo apenas quando a $_SESSION[nivelAcesso]==3. Sou um pouco recente no PHP...

Comment: @TiagoMartins entendi. Alterei a resposta, veja se agora resolve o problema.

Comment: deu certo aqui, ajudou demais! Abraço.